# Domain discretization

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

While approximating the domains in order to apply the finite element methods for Navier Stokes Equations, we have used 2 different meshes for the same domain.

In general why we may need 2 meshes for the same domain (our 2 variables are $u$ the velocity of the fluid and $p$ the pressure of the fluid)? Is it to ensure stability? If yes, how could I know what mesh I have to choose to ensure stability?

Comment: Could you please be more specific / give us more details?

Comment: @HandeBruijn I think this can be a general case, according to what conditions we choose the mesh? It’s sometimes twice coarser for a variable than the other in the same problem

Comment: Yeah, I know: twice coarser for the pressure in comparison with the velocities. But why? Wish I knew a precise answer, other than "it works".

Comment: @HandeBruijn yes, this is exactly what I want to know, Do you know someone who can help?

Comment: @HandeBruijn I have another question(in numerical analysis,operator splitting), can you help?

Comment: Why not just formulate it as a new question and see if someone can help? Please be specific.

Comment: @HandeBruijn https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767002/operator-splitting ,here is the question, I didn’t formulate it because I have found a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Well if i remember correctly we use two meshes for the same domain to make sure that velocity-pressure coupling satisfy the LBB condition. Like we use a Q1Q1 or Q2Q1 bubble function elements to solve such problems since these elements satisfy the LBB condition. Since it's a very vast topic I have only mentioned in the general scene. If you want to look for detailed explanation i would recommend you to read the chapter 6 of the book "Finite Element Methods for Flow Problems" by Jean Donea and Antonio Huerta.

I have the original copy of this book so if you could't find the soft copy  let me know i can send you a pdf copy of the book.